# Esami package: parameters inside fractions and roots

Tags: esami

I am using the package "esami" with parameters. I have to write the number √(a/b) where a and b are parameters, with all the possible numeric simplifications. For example I want √(8/2) to be written as 2 (and not √4).

There is the command `\sempli{a}{b}` that semplifies the fractions and the command `\simpsqrt` that semplifies radicals, is there a way to have both radical and fracion simplified in the same operation?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the answer is no. Root simplification of the result of a simplified fraction is still an open problem in the esami package.